# SQLState 42000 syntax error. Possible table issue?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I'm stuck with a syntax error for a SQL query to insert data into a table.
Ah, the syntax error, most useless of all errors!!

Using the code modified from [PHP Insert Data Into MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) using both mysqli and PDO methods.
e.g.:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "4w_write";
$password = "GjByhJzrQueHgTzw";
$dbname = "4w_test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO 4w (email) VALUES ($email)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Having stripped it down to a single variable which isn't using a keyword, I'm pretty sure the problem is with my table.

SQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO 4w (email) VALUES (myemail@gmail.com)
```

Error:

> Error: INSERT INTO 4w (email) VALUES (myemail@gmail.com) You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com)'
>   at line 1

SQL table (4w):

```
#   Name                 Type       Default 
1   id [Primary,Index]   int(11)
2   email                varchar(255)
3   whatIs               tinytext
4   whereIs              text
5   whattodo             text
6   imageURL             text
7   whenRep              timestamp  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Invalid SQL, strings need to be quoted. You also would be better to parameterize. `$email` also is undefined?

Comment: $email is defined elsewhere, and this block in included... Done that way to debug whether it was a particular way that was causing the problem. Yes, untidy...

Comment: Thanks EL_DON.  There was a problem. Missing quotes in the SQL query. But sure. Be mean to the new guy...

Answer (score 1):

The email value is a string, so you need to surround it with quotes:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 4w (email) VALUES ('$email')";
```

Or, better yet, use a prepared statement and bind it's value.

Comment: Baby steps.... Can't learn it all in a day... Now I get SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' but at least it is progress... Now to get it to autoincrement properly...

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't see the problem, missing quotes....
Original code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 4w (email) VALUES ($email)";
```

Fixed code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 4w (email) VALUES ('$email')";
```